# Booting from network

Tags: boot, pxe, live-environment

Is it possible to boot (without actually installing it) ubuntu and run Ubuntu desktop image via PXE like a Live CD? I don't want the session to actually preserve state. Each boot should be fresh and alike. Is it possible to achieve this via PXE boot.

Also when a machine is booted via PXE, after the OS has loaded, which machine's resources does the OS consume? The client's or the PXE server's? I believe it should be latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a TFTP-Server and put a Ubuntu-Live Image on it, to boot it via PXE on another machine. This is a fresh Live-Disk on every reboot.

The resources of the machine on which the Live-Disk is runnig will be used.
But the HDD will not be touched. The Live-Ubuntu is running on a ramdisk.

You can get the Images for an Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 here:
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz

This is für Ubuntu 12.10 32 bit:
http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/netboot.tar.gz

EDIT: I found an example for a TFTP-config:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveCDNetboot

Comment: It wouldn't quite scale if I want to run 500 machines from a single server. Is there way by which server can just provide a live image and defer booting to client?

Comment: The Server will only provide the image and let the Client boot from it. Some files will be copied to the clients RAM. That it. Everything else happens on the Client. You can shutdown the Server when the client has beootet if you want.

Comment: Nice, thats all I want.